# Contaminating in CSV file. Comma in column with value of thousands

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have I think small problem with the data cleaning. In enclosed CSV file [enter link to CSV](http://sigmaquality.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/runways.csv). Somebody had put comma in the column "length ft" in row 7. I pointed where on the picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0yCs.png)

```
 df=pd.read_csv('c:/2/runways.csv', error_bad_lines  = True)
 print(df)

 df=pd.read_csv('c:/2/runways.csv', thousands=',')
 print(df)

 df=pd.read_csv('c:/2/runways.csv', decimal = ',')
```

Instruction above that I know doesn't work.
Method of data cleaning is crucial to me.
Please help me.
Every help will be awarded (when I will be over 15 reputation).

Comment: If you can't tell whatever idiot that generated the file to generate you a correct new one... then the only thing you can really do is re-detect the columns by content type; filter out badly split columns by checking columns behind it that are supposed to specifically have number or non-number content in them.

Comment: Wait, there are no thousand separators in that data at all, and it uses dot for decimal points. I don't see the problem...

Comment: Sorry - I admit in that file was all right. Now I changed file. You can see it again. I have problem with commas who somebody manually put in the thousand. If you ones again see what is wrong in my instructions.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked too close at the data file, but it seems to follow a pretty simple pattern: `#,#,"cccc",#,#...` (where `#` is a number and `c` is an alphanumeric character).

That pattern can be fairly easily translated into a regular expression pattern like: `^(\d+,\d+,"[\dA-Z]{4}",)(\d+),(\d{3},\d+)` This RegEx pattern will detect lines that contain 3 sets of comma separated numbers between the "airport_ident" and "surface" fields, and more importantly, it will only match when the second number of that set is exactly 3 digits long because this would indicate that the comma was intended as a thousands separator.

Due to the grouping, you can utilize back referencing to replace the thousands separators. E.g., messing with this in Atom (text editor), I used a RegEx replacement pattern of `$1$2$3`, since the thousands separator comma falls outside the second and third capturing groups. In python, that would be something like

```
import re

raw_lines = ""
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as fh:
    raw_lines = fh.read()

cleaned_lines = re.sub(
        r'^(\d+,\d+,"[\dA-Z]{4}",)(\d+),(\d{3},\d+)',
        r'\1\2\3',
        raw_lines,
        re.IGNORECASE
)
```

That said, as run-out reported in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620400/2694511), I did not see any problematic lines when I opened the CSV file in a text-editor.

Answer (score 1):

I opened your csv file in excel and the excel engine seems to have dealt with the comma. I'm showing 1700 in the length_ft column. When I save this file as xlsx instead of csv, and then use pd.read_excel('runways.xlsx'), the file seems to open correctly.   Excel version is Office 2010 professional plus.

```
    id  airport_ref airport_ident   length_ft   width_ft    surface lighted closed  le_ident    le_latitude_deg le_longitude_deg    le_elevation_ft le_heading_degT le_displaced_threshold_ft   he_ident    he_latitude_deg he_longitude_deg    he_elevation_ft he_heading_degT he_displaced_threshold_ft
0   269408  6523    00A     80.0    80.0    ASPH-G  1   0   H1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   255155  6524    00AK    2500.0  70.0    GRVL    0   0   N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN S   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   254165  6525    00AL    2300.0  200.0   TURF    0   0   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 19  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   270932  6526    00AR    40.0    40.0    GRASS   0   0   H1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN H1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   322128  322127  00AS    1450.0  60.0    Turf    0   0   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 19  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   257681  6527    00AZ    1700.0  60.0    GRAVEL  0   0   15  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 33  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   245528  6528    00CA    6000.0  80.0    ASPH    0   0   4   35.3493 -116.8930   NaN 50.0    NaN 22  35.3603 -116.8780   NaN NaN NaN
7   250597  6529    00CO    3900.0  20.0    TURF-G  0   0
```